# Design and Implementation of Generics part 2

Tags: .net, generics, clr

In a very interesting paper [Design and Implementation of Generics for the
.NET Common Language Runtime](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/akenn/generics/DesignAndImplementationOfGenerics.pdf) by Andrew Kennedy and Don Syme, the authors claim that

> Finally we note that polymorphic [meaning generic] virtual methods are altogether
>   more challenging. […] We will discuss
>   efficient solutions to […] these problems in a future paper.

Does that future paper exist? If yes, where can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, it's either [Formalization of Generics for the .NET Common Language Runtime](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64032) by Dachuan Yu, Andrew J. Kennedy, and Don Syme or [Transposing F to C#: Expressivity of polymorphism in an object-oriented language](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=69128) by Don Syme and Andrew Kennedy.

But neither talks much about virtual generic methods.